# Wix - are there any authentication and authorization apps?

Tags: authentication, authorization, velo

I'm building a fairly simple Wix website.

I want a members app that can do the following:

- Have a sign up page that sends an email to the site administrator. Once the site administrator approves they are approved and can log in.
- Give users the option to sign up as either a standard or advanced access user. If they are an advanced user, then they can access different pages to the standard user.

aka. authorization and authentication

I looked at using the [Wix members app](http://www.wix.com/app-market/member-login/overview), but this does not seem to include authorization.

Perhaps there is no Wix solution and I would be better off creating the site from scratch, with something like ASP.NET user account authentication?

Comment: Anyone who knows why this might have been downvoted - please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I received from the Wix team is:

"I believe the best way to achieve what you are trying to achieve is password protect all of your site pages except the home page.

You can add a contact form so users can contact you and ask for the password to access the rest of your site pages.

Then, as you mentioned, you can add a Member Login App to allow your visitors to sign up for the other restricted part of the site (authorization), and add a PayPal button so they can pay for their subscription (if needed). Then you can approve members who have paid for their subscription."

I will be using forms based auth with an MVC app instead to overcome this issue as the Wix solution I do not believe would provide a good user experience.